# validacion de etiqueta en XSD

Tags: html, xml, xsd, xml-schema

Buen dia,

Alguien conoce si existe forma de validar en el XSD lo siguiente:
Cuando en el TAG  tenga el valor SER sea obligatorio registrar el tag  caso contrario si el valor  es EQU sea opcional

Estoy utilizando la versión XSD 1.0 y no encuentro forma de realizar esta validacion

Esto solo se puede hacer con XSD 1.1?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

### Adjunto el XML y XSD

```html
<REQUERIMIENTO>
 <DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
  <ID_PLAN>BP-7138</ID_PLAN>
  <ID_SUBPRODUCTO>AUT</ID_SUBPRODUCTO>
  <CANTIDAD>1</CANTIDAD>
  <TIPO>SER</TIPO>
  <DETALLES_SERVICIOS>
   <NOMBRE_USUARIO>JANIO</NOMBRE_USUARIO>
   <NUMERO_SERIE>12345</NUMERO_SERIE>
   <IN_BODEGA>130</IN_BODEGA>
  </DETALLES_SERVICIOS>
 </DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
 <DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
  <ID_PLAN>0</ID_PLAN>
  <ID_SUBPRODUCTO>SAMSUNG A510 G</ID_SUBPRODUCTO>
  <CANTIDAD>1</CANTIDAD>
  <TIPO>EQU</TIPO>
 </DETALLES_SOLICITUDES>
</REQUERIMIENTO>
```

### XSD

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="REQUERIMIENTO">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DETALLES_SOLICITUDES">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID_PLAN" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ID_SUBPRODUCTO" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="CANTIDAD" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="TIPO">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="SER"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="EQU"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DETALLES_SERVICIOS">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="NOMBRE_USUARIO" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="NUMERO_SERIE" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                    <xs:element name="IN_BODEGA" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Para realizar ese tipo de validaciones debes usar archivos .XSL. http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-xsd-and-xsl/

Comment: Estudie sobre los archivos .XSL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor/Basic_Example otro ejemplo http://www.ldodds.com/papers/schematron_xsltuk.html

Comment: @EverZevallos XSL sirve para dar estilo a un archivo XML. Lo que el usuario busca es definir un formato específico para un archivo XML (que un elemento sea opcional u obligatorio dependiendo de un valor), para lo que se usa XSD.